# CakePHP: When I change User session i get logout

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication, admin

I need to add possibility of Admin to enter User account, but i stucked when i change session data, i got logout.

`$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['username']=$user_data['User']['username'];`

To come back into admin session I made new variable

`$_SESSION['Auth']['Admin']['id']=$user_id`

Please help me to change admin data into user, and add possibility to come back as admin when logout

Comment: I called that [user-switching](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/12/15/user-switch-for-cakephp-apps/), but PGBI is right, login($data) does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To login as a user when your are admin you can do this:

In your controller:

```
$user = $this->User->findById($idOfUserYouWantToLoginAs);
... // handle case where $user is empty
$this->Auth->login($user['User']);
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was trying to login with username or id, change session, i knew that solution must be something simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just change the variables in the session as needed. I did it yesterday just changing the id of the logged user, but you can also change the stored username or email address or anything on session:

```
$this->Session->write('Auth.User.id',$newLoggedUserId);
$this->Session->write('Auth.User.username',$newLoggedUserName);
$this->Session->write('Auth.User.email',$newLoggedUserEmail);
```